# To jump the same route in vue js not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

First link is http://127.0.0.1:8000/subkategoriya/23
I want to jump this route but only param will be changed, like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/subkategoriya/24

```
<li v-for="subcategory in subcategories"  :key="subcategory.id">
  <router-link 
    :to="{name: 'subcatprods', params:{ id:subcategory.id }}" 
    @click="changed">
      {{subcategory.category_tm}}
  </router-link>
</li>
```

```
methods: {
  changed() {
    // update
  }
}
```

How can I code in this method `changed()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused because the same component is reused, which is done for performance reasons. You can workaround this in two ways. Either by watching the route for param changes or hooking into the route update.

Here is an example reacting to the prop changing and updating the message displayed. Click the links to see it and you can comment out the update in the watch to see it fail to update. http://jsfiddle.net/9k7hdwse/

From the docs:

```
export default {
    watch: {
        $route(to, from) {
            // do update
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can use `beforeRouteUpdate`:

```
export default {
    beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
        // do update
        next();
    }
}
```

More information can be found here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

Comment: can you demonstrate how to use it in this situation

Comment: I added a jsfiddle